# Symfony2 - Twig - Issue displaying data

Tags: symfony, twig

I have run the query that returns quite a bit of data. In my controller I do

```
public function viewAction()
{
        $repository = $this
            ->getDoctrine()
            ->getManager()
            ->getRepository('NickAlertBundle:AvailabilityAlert');

        $alerts = $repository->getAllActiveAlerts();
        var_dump($alerts);

        return $this->render('NickAlertBundle:Page:view.html.twig', array(
            'alert' => $alerts,
        ));
}
```

That `var_dump` contains the data I need, it looks like

```
array (size=2)
  0 => 
    array (size=4)
      0 => 
        object(Nick\AlertBundle\Entity\AvailabilityAlert)[320]
          private 'id' => int 34
          private 'searchCommand' => string 'LONMEL' (length=12)
          private 'isConnecting' => string 'no' (length=2)
          private 'lastUpdated' => 
            object(DateTime)[323]
              ...
          private 'isDeleted' => boolean false
          private 'alertStatus' => string 'Active' (length=6)
      'classes' => string 'Business' (length=3)
      'flight_number' => string 'VS7' (length=3)
  1 => 
    ....
```

How would I go about getting this data displaying in my Twig file?  I have tried

```
{{ alert.getSearchCommand() }}
{{ alert.searchCommand }}
{{ alert }}
```

But most of the time I get the following error:

> An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("Notice: Array to string conversion")

So I was wondering how can I get this data displaying correctly?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Symfony2 - Twig - Issue displaying content](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28517355/symfony2-twig-issue-displaying-content)

Answer (score 4):

You need to loop over your array. You can do it with twig [**for**](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/for.html) :

In your case, something like this :

#### In controller :

I renamed your variable from alert to alerts as there can be more than one.

```
return $this->render('NickAlertBundle:Page:view.html.twig', array(
    'alerts' => $alerts,
));
```

#### In your twig file :

```
{% for alert in alerts %}
    //here you can access your entity
    {{ alert.searchCommand }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: I did attempt that, but I still have a problem with it complaining about array keys.  I think it may be because I have a multidimensional array?