# Symfony2 - Twig - Issue displaying content

Tags: symfony, twig

I pass some data to my template.  When I dump the data it looks like so

```
array:2 [▼
  0 => array:4 [▼
    0 => AvailabilityAlert {#320 ▼
      -id: 34
      -searchCommand: "A01APRLONBAG"
      -isConnecting: "no"
      -lastUpdated: DateTime {#323 ▶}
      -isDeleted: false
      -alertStatus: "Active"
    }
    "classes" => "C,D"
    "flight_number" => "VS7"
  ]
  1 => ...
```

Essentially, its a multi dimensional array, but inside there is an Object (AvailabilityAlert) and some other data.  I am trying to render this data in my template.

Getting the additional data (classes, flight_number) to display is easy

```
{% for alert in alerts %}
    {{  alert.classes }}
    {{  alert.pseudos }}
    {{  alert.flight_number }}
{% endfor %}
```

However, I am not sure how to get the Objects data displaying.  If I try

```
{% for alert in alerts %}

    {% for a in alert %}
        <tr>

            <td><a href="">{{ a.searchCommand }}</a></td>
             <td>{{ a.isConnecting }}</td>
             <td>{% if a.lastUpdated %}{{ a.lastUpdated|date('Y-m-d H:i:s') }}{% endif %}</td>
             <td>{{ a.isDeleted }}</td>
             <td>{{ a.alertStatus }}</td>
             <td>{{ a.id }}</td>
             <td>
                 <ul>
                     <li>
                         <a href="">show</a>
                     </li>
                 </ul>
             </td>
        </tr>
    {% endfor %}

    {{  alert.classes }}
    {{  alert.pseudos }}
    {{  alert.flight_number }}

{% endfor %}
```

I get the error

> Impossible to access an attribute ("searchCommand") on a string variable ("C,D")

So how would I display this Object as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `alert[0].searchCommand` instead of `a.searchCommand`, it should help :) That nested loop is not needed.